# Visual Code pylint: unable to import webapp2 and google.appengine.api

Tags: python, visual-studio, google-app-engine, visual-studio-code, pylint

I am new to using Visual Code on Ubtuntu... But I followed all necessary instructions to install google app engine for python. 
Then on writing my python code on the Visual Code, which I already modified my USER SETTINGS :

```
{ 
 "python.autoComplete.extraPaths": [
    "/usr/local/google_appengine",
    "/usr/local/google_appengine/lib"],
"python.autoComplete.addBrackets": true,
"workbench.welcome.enabled": false,
"workbench.iconTheme": "vscode-icons",
"python.pythonPath": "/usr/bin/python", 
}
```

[image: pylinting on my python code]

Please how I can resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

Add the following library paths to your `"python.autoComplete.extraPaths"` list:

```
"/usr/local/google_appengine/api",
"/usr/local/google_appengine/lib/webapp2-2.5.2"
```